# Команды для QPushButton

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

Предположим что я добавил 2 кнопки `QPushButton` в окно и хочу добавить на них такие функции как "Закрыть окно" и "Свернуть окно". Как это сделать?

Т.е. при нажатии первой кнопки окно полностью должно закрываться, а при нажатии второй кнопки должно сворачиваться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Тоесть при нажатии первой кнопки окно полностью должно закрываться,

Вызывайте метод [close()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#close)

> а при нажатии второй кнопки должно сворачиваться.

Вызывайте метод [showMinimized()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#showMinimized)

---

Например:

```
button_close.clicked.connect(self.close)
button_minimize.clicked.connect(self.showMinimized)
```